# Creating Unity appindicator icons

Tags: unity, indicator, icons

I want to create attention appindicator icon for my application. They are usually blue color, but I need exact color code in order to make it integrate in unity well. I found nothing on http://unity.ubuntu.com/projects/appindicators/.

So, I need exact colors for dark (Radience), light (Ambiance) and attention (blue).

Can someone help?

There must be some guidline for creating this icons.

Comment: If you are looking for the way to add an icon to your indicator, [here is a nice tutorial for python](http://candidtim.github.io/appindicator/2014/09/13/ubuntu-appindicator-step-by-step.html).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The hexadecimal RGBA color codes for indicators are:

- Ambiance (ubuntu-mono-dark): `dfd8c8ff`
- Radiance (ubuntu-mono-light): `3a3935ff`
- Attention (blue): `19b6eeff`

Answer (score 5):

The icons used aren't in the themes although a particular icon set may be associated with a theme. The icon sets are stored in /usr/share/icons. If the icon set in use is for example "ubuntu-mono-dark" look in the folder /usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/status. Status is the where the icons you're interested are stored regardless of the icon set you're using. Inside status will be folders for each size that can be used. Modern icons are frequently scale-able with an .svg extension rather than png which are fixed size. If you open a similar icon to the what you plan to create in gimp for png and inkscape for svg you'll be able to see and match the colors of the icon. Gimp provides an eye dropper tool to extract color from ant image it can edit. You may notice that although mostly monochromatic these icons do have a shadow which an editor like gimp can create for you.